# if I exit the project and enter again the migration does not find the Context anymore

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, model, scaffolding, scaffold

If I leave the project and enter again and make some changes to the Model and then do the migration again, it gives me this problem, why does this happen???

"
Add-Migration MyText -Context MyContext
Add-Migration : Cannot find a parameter that matches the parameter name 'Context'.
No line:1 caractere:50

- Add-Migration MyText -Context MyContext...
- ```
                                               ~~~~~~~~
  ```

  - CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Add-Migration], ParameterBindingException
  - FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Add-Migration

"

Comment: I'm a little fuzzy on this these days but does the terminal window have a dropdown list in the top bar to choose a "project"? If so this would be the way to tell VS that you want to run this command for the project selected (if not - ignore me).

Comment: I copied wrong, sorry!

I think I found the problem, it worked if I put the "EntityframeworkCore" before

So the command would look like this
Add-Migration MyText -Context EntityframeworkCore/MyContext

I don't know exactly why this is, but I'm still going to do more tests.